# Grid1 does not exist error when loading xml to html table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load an XML data to a table in ASP.NET. I tried adding the following code in page_load

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("xmlName.xml"));
Grid1.DataSource = ds;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

But it is showing an error

```
Grid1 is does not exist in the current context
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Verify that `Grid1` is defined in your markup, like this:

```
<asp:GridView id="Grid1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: If you don't mind that the column names will match the columns in the data set, then you can use `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` in your markup and omit the `.DataBind()` call, like this:

```
<asp:GridView id="Grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

</asp:GridView>
```

Now you can omit the `Columns` definitions in the grid view markup and also remove the `.DataBind()` call so you only need to set the `DataSource` property.

Comment: thanks for the reply..but now the issue is that the data is not getting displayed in the web page. My current code is something like         <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView id="Grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
           <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" ReadOnly="True"   
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />  
         </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
        </div>
</asp:Content>

Comment: Did you put a break point on the `Grid1.DataSource = ds;` line and verify that `ds` has something in it?

Comment: The input xml structure is <Names><Name><FirstName>Amelia</FirstName><LastName>Earhart</LastName></Name></Names>...I think I am not accessing the correct level of xml. Not sure.

Comment: the issue was solved when i set ViewStateMode="Enabled" in the mark up.

Answer (score 0):

```
make Grid1 property runat='server'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a bit of context to this answer. Full context w/ the ASP.NET for example

Answer (score 0):

`Grid1` should have the attribute - `runat="server"` for you to be able to access it from your code behind

Note:
**It's only effective when all the root to this element has this attribute.**